# How to create a outer circle in chart?

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I am creating a web application in which there is a requirement of creating a chart. I have successfully created zoom pie chart but now there is a requirement for creating an outer circle of pie chart. I have no idea about how to create that.

Any suggestions are acceptable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this would be to create a doughnut chart for your outer circle.To accommodate the inner circle, Set the CSS property **position to absolute** and give it a **higher Z index**. Then, adjust the radius accordingly to fit the scale.

Comment: technically it is not possible, placing a second chart into 1st doughnut chart's center.